# How solve this problem with lower bounds in sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\lambda (B)$ is denoted like the $\textit{lower bound of B}$.

> Suppose $B \subseteq A$ and $C \subseteq A$; prove that $\lambda(B \cup C)=\lambda(B) \cap \lambda(C)$

Let $x\in \lambda(B \cup C)
\implies (\forall y\in (B\cup C))y \geq x  
\implies (\forall y\in B \lor y\in C) y\geq x$

I'm stuck here, because that seems like $\lambda(B) \cup \lambda(C)$, and trying to show $\lambda(B) \cap \lambda(C)\subseteq \lambda(B \cup C)$, i need use other letters.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Isn't $\lambda(B)$ supposed to be a real number and not a set?

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife $\lambda (B)$ is a set, because is the set who contains the lower bounds of the set $B$

Answer (score 1):

Given $x$, we have that
\begin{align} x\in\lambda(B\cup C) &\Leftrightarrow x\leq y,\ \forall y\in B\cup C \\&\Leftrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{l}x\leq y,\ \forall y\in B \\ 
x\leq y,\ \forall y\in C\end{array}\right. \\&\Leftrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{l}x\in\lambda(B) \\ x\in \lambda(C)\end{array}\right.\\&\Leftrightarrow\ x\in \lambda(B)\cap\lambda(C),\end{align}
so the sets $\lambda(B\cup C)$ and $\lambda(B)\cap\lambda(C)$ must be equal.

We shall prove the second equivalence by proving that the negations are equivalent. Note that

\begin{align}
\neg(\forall y\in B\cup C,x\leq y) &\Leftrightarrow \exists y\in B\cup C:\neg(x\leq y) \\&\Leftrightarrow(\exists y\in B:\neg(x\leq y))\vee(\exists y\in C:\neg(x\leq y)) \\&\Leftrightarrow\neg(\forall y\in B,x\leq y)\vee\neg(\forall y\in C,x\leq y) \\&\Leftrightarrow\neg[(\forall y\in B,x\leq y)\wedge(\forall y\in C,x\leq y)]
\end{align}

Comment: Can you use more logical propositions?. I do not understand what the bracket means, is it an "$\lor$" or a  "$\land$" "?

Comment: The bracket is a $\wedge$.

Comment: Try to prove the second equivalence by contrapositive.

Comment: If the bracket is $\land$, why you say $\forall y\in (B\cup C) \implies y\in B \land y\in C$?

Comment: No, the bracket is applyed over the formulas, so I meant that $ (x\leq y,\ \forall y\in B\cup C) \Leftrightarrow (x\leq y,\ \forall y\in B)\wedge(x\leq y,\ \forall y\in C)$